# How to remove space above of cell in tableview using navigation contoller in swift?

Tags: ios

When using navigation controller then give space above of cell (give dark color in image of tableview).

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6gw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6gw.png)

Comment: Provide more information. Do u want to remove tableview cell separator?

Answer (score 1):

you need to uncheck Adjust scroll view insets 
[image]